# how can i display the records from the SQl server database in an array using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I have an online Job application site, where I am trying to query the positions from database(MS SQL Server).

I have queried the database using `sqlsrv_fetch_array`, where I am getting the position list in an array.

But I would like to display the array in this format.

```
<?php

    $select = array (
    'Province1' => 
      array ( 
        'City1' => 
        array (
          ID => 'Position1',
          ID => 'Position2',
        )    
      ),
    'Province2' => 
      array ( 
        'City2' => 
        array (
          ID => 'Position3',
          ID => 'Position4', 
        )   
      ),
   );
?>
```

Database:

![enter image description here][1]

I am currently using this code:

```
$tsql = "SELECT * FROM Jobs";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
    echo "".$row[0]."<br>\n";
    echo "".$row[1]."<br>\n";
    echo "".$row[2]."<br>\n";
    echo "".$row[3]."<br>\n";
}
```

[Please see the screen shot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoPac.png)

Comment: sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH) // try this

Comment: ↑ this parameter is already default.

Comment: Convert your table into xml, then pass this XML to php, parse XML as array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic way to do this is to just define the different levels of grouping in your result array as you fetch rows from your query result:

```
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_object($stmt)) {
    $result[$row->Province][$row->City][$row->ID] = $row->Position;
}
```

Each time you want another level of grouping in your result, just add another key like I've shown there.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details rather than using comments, especially with code. It's very difficult to read it that way, among other problems.

Comment: Hi  , I am new to stack overflow . I was trying to put the code in the correct format ,but it resulted in that format .sorry

Comment: It's OK! There's definitely a bit of a learning curve. I find the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) is usually very helpful.

Comment: <while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_object( $stmt))    
   {    
    
$result[$row->Province][$row->City][$row->ID] = $row->Position;
     
   }>

Comment: The Above code is not fetching the results from the results

Comment: This code just builds the result array. It doesn't output anything. You should be able to see it with `var_dump($result)`. How to format the output is up to you.

Comment: I have updated the Question with the screen shot of the Careers page that has to  display the positions